How to figure out from EntryRemovedListener if the entry is evicted or deleted?
I am using RMapCache where setMaxSize is set.
Can someone tell me if there is a way for me to know in EntryRemovedListener if the entry is evicted (due to maxSize being reached) or if the removal is due to the explicit call of remove()?
The only way I can think of is the one below, but I'm not sure how accurate this will be or whether this is even recommended.
map.addListener(
        (EntryRemovedListener<String, V>)
            event -> {
                  if (event.getSource().size == maxSize) {
                        log.info("Entry evicted due to max size being reached");
                  }
             });

Can someone suggest if the above is recommended or if a better approach exists?
Redisson Version - 3.32.0
